Fluent validation check to pass only one query parameter from given 2 query parameter
I have get web api where I need to write down fluent validation which we check user can only pass one query parameter.
I have 2 parameters name as action and promo.where parameters types are boolean
If user pass action=true & promo=true then fluent validation throw error.
How I can achieve it in . Net core web api
I was trying to use
public class productrequest : AbstractValidator<productrequest>
{
    public productrequest()
    {
        RuleFor(a=>a.action).Must(RuleFor(a=>a.promo).Null());
    }
}

But it give me compile time error

Cannot covert from IRulebuilderOption<productrequest, bool?
to System.Func<bool?,bool)'

Can someone please suggest right approach for it

The method .Must() requires a Func<bool,bool> - RuleFor() does not match that type.
However, .Must() has an overload that accepts Func<productrequest,bool,bool> which seems to be closer to what you wanted to do there.
Also, .Null() would require action to be null which would be counterintuitive as you expect it to be true or false.
The following example seems to be closer to what you may have intended:
public class productrequest : AbstractValidator<productrequest>
{
    public bool action; //included for clarity
    public bool promo; //included for clarity

    public productrequest()
    {
        RuleFor(a => a.action).Must((a, _, y) => a.action ? !a.promo : true).NotNull();            
    }
}


(a, _, y) => !(a.action & a.promo) - it isn't allowed for both parameters to be true

@AdamSilenko in the expression I wrote, if a.action is true, it checks the status of a.promo - if it is also true, the ! turns it into false and returns that. Yours is more simplified though

You have right.
